# How to set all files in AWS S3 to private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've got a bunch of files, some inside of folders, which I would like to change to private. i.e. I would like to remove `Everyone` from the `Permission`'s tab.

I tried using Amazon Web Console to no avail. Should I consider another tool for the task?

Using Firefox S3 Organizer or Bucket Explorer to change all file's ACL will not work if you have several hundreds. They just freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html did it. It was also able to set ACL permissions for files that had a different owner. Bucket Explorer couldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the left column of the S3 console. Right-click on your bucket and select properties. Then under the permissions tab you can delete "everyone".

Comment: Tried that. Deleting "Everyone" doesn't do much, especially if the files have their own permission.

Comment: You can download something like Cloudberry Explorer - http://www.cloudberrylab.com/ - which makes it easier. (I'm not affiliate to that company) Have not used it since I change my laptop to Linux a yr ago. But it was able to do all of very well. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

For many activities on S3 objects, like copying them, etc a default ACL (no ACL, private) is applied on each action. There is also a PUT ACL command in AWS.

It would not take a lot of Ruby code to dive through a repo and call PUTACL on each file, with private.

Answer (score 0):

First, install `s3cmd` (sudo apt-get install s3cmd) or download from amazon

Then run this command `s3cmd setacl s3://[your_bucket]/path/to/the/folder/ --acl-private --recursive`

For more information, please check here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/s3cmd